# How to show configurable product stock status?

Tags: ajax, magento, product, stock

I have this phtml file which shows stock status:

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct() ?>
<?php $productQty = (int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty(); ?>
<?php if ($productQty > 100): ?>
    <div class="catalog-stock over-stock">
        <span class="qry-text"><?php echo $this->__('In stock:'); ?></span>
        <span class="qry-count">100+</span>
    </div>
<?php elseif ($productQty > 0 && $productQty <= 100): ?>
    <div class="catalog-stock normal-stock">
        <span class="qry-text"><?php echo $this->__('In stock:'); ?></span>
        <span class="qry-count"><?php echo $productQty; ?></span>
    </div>
<?php elseif ($deliveryDate = $_product->getStockDeliveryDate()): ?>
    <div class="catalog-stock no-stock">
        <span class="qry-text"><?php echo $this->__('Expected'); ?></span>
        <span class="qry-count"><?php echo $deliveryDate; ?></span>
    </div>
<?php elseif ($_product->getTypeId() != 'configurable' && $_product->getTypeId() != 'grouped' && $_product->getTypeId() != 'bundle'): ?>
    <div class="catalog-stock no-stock">
        <span class="qry-text"><?php echo $this->__('Expected'); ?></span>
        <span class="qry-count"><?php echo $this->__('n/a'); ?></span>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I call it with this line `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>` from product/view/view.phtml

When used with simple product it works perfectly, but how to do same thing with configurable product?

What I want is to change stock status depending on what configurations is selected.

One solution is to check if product is configurable and then display all values at same time and hide with css. But if I do this I have problem - how to know which product is selected and show it's stock status?

I guess best option would be to do this with ajax, but I spent hours trying to do that and didn't succeed.

Comment: you will definitely need some client side scripting in there as the value will need to be updated when the user selects a new child product (variant)

Comment: you need to fire off an ajax request based on the child product ID, once you have the product ID of the child the above method will work fine as the stock value comes from the associated child (simple) product. Basically call a similar script to above from an ajax request, passing in the simple/child product ID will work fine

Comment: and how do I do that? how to assign product id to options?

Comment: I managed to add product ID to option, but how to call that phtml file and give it selected ID?

Comment: Whats your action? means which your URL your get alerted when your click that attribute?

Comment: you could make a custom controller and just return the stock value from the action